# $f$ measurable, $g$ either 1 or 0 if $f$ rational or irrational

Tags: measure-theory

I have trouble advancing with this problem, though it seemed quite straight forward at glance.

$f$ is a measurable function, and let

$$g(x)=
\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  0  & \mbox{if } f(x)&\mbox{is rational} \\
  1 & \mbox{if } f(x)&\mbox{is irrational}
 \end{array}
\right.$$

show g is measurable

I know the definition of measurability with preimage and such, but I don't have the space or sigma algebras given. Isn't that necessary? I struggle to apply the definition with only the above given information. I'm probably missing something.

any tip or hint would be great! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you are trying to show that $g$ is measurable.

I am assuming that single points are measurable.
Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable, it is measurable, as is its complement $\mathbb{Q}^c$.

Hence $A= f^{-1} \mathbb{Q}^c$ is measurable. Hence $g= 1_A$ is measurable.